# How do I convert date and seconds fields to a timestamp field in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, timestamp

I have a date field, which is just text, and a field showing seconds since midnight.

```
CREATE TABLE t ("s" text, "d" text, "ts" timestamp)
;   
INSERT INTO t ("s", "d")
VALUES
    (24855, 20130604),
    (24937.7, 20130604)
;
```

How can I convert these fields into a timestamp, so I can run time-based queries?

See a demo with SQL Fiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/67018/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your data includes fractional seconds, you need to adjust for those:

```
UPDATE t
SET    ts = to_timestamp(d||s, 'YYYYMMDDSSSS.MS');
```

Assuming milliseconds as the maximum precision. Else employ `US` for microseconds.

Consider the [fine print in the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-formatting.html):

> In a conversion from string to `timestamp`, millisecond (`MS`) or
>   microsecond (`US`) values are used as the seconds digits after the
>   decimal point. For example `to_timestamp('12:3', 'SS:MS')` is not 3
>   milliseconds, but 300, because the conversion counts it as 12 + 0.3
>   seconds. This means for the format `SS:MS`, the input values `12:3`,
>   `12:30`, and `12:300` specify the same number of milliseconds. To get
>   three milliseconds, one must use `12:003`, which the conversion counts
>   as 12 + 0.003 = 12.003 seconds.

Also note that `to_timestamp()` returns [`timestamp with time zone`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-datetime.html), which is coerced to `timestamp` in the context of the update, which turns out all right. For other contexts, you may want to cast explicitly or use this alternative, yielding `timestamp`:

```
SELECT d::date + interval '1s' * s::numeric AS ts FROM t;
```

The plain cast to date (`d::date`) works because your dates are in standard ISO 8601 format - or so I assume.

Comment: Thank you for your more complete answer. I squinted at your SELECT statement for a minute before I noticed order of operations means 1 second would be multiplied by seconds before being added to date. Yes? I would feel safer with some parentheses.

Comment: @MartinBurch: Yes, that's dictated by **[operator precedence](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-PRECEDENCE)**. You can add parentheses for clarity, but the expression is valid as it is.

Answer (score 1):

[Concatenate](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-string.html) the two fields together and then use [`to_timestamp()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-formatting.html)

`UPDATE t SET ts = to_timestamp(d||s, 'YYYYMMDDSSSS');`

For a discussion of the formatting string used in to_timestamp, see [Table 9-21: Template Patterns for Date/Time Formatting](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-DATETIME-TABLE) in the PostgreSQL documentation.