# Rails: How to query for rows by subtracting column value from datetime column?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, datetime

Running Rails 4 with PostgreSQL.

I have a column that stores a datetime value and another that stores an integer value which represents a timespan in seconds.

How can I query for rows where the datetime column value minus the integer (timespan) value is older than the current time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the Rails equivalent of what you're asking about

```
Model.where(%q{datetime_col - seconds_col * interval '1 second' < now()})
```

for whatever values of `Model`, `datetime_col`, `seconds_col` you're using.

Comment: I suggest to copy the sargable expression from my answer, not the inferior one.

Answer (score 1):

`datetime`? You mean [`timestamp`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-datetime.html) I assume? I'll further assume this table (for lack of information):

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (
   tbl_id  serial PRIMARY KEY
  ,ts      timestamp
  ,seconds integer
  );
```

> where the datetime column value minus the integer (timespan) value is older than the current time?

The query is simple:

```
SELECT *
FROM   tbl
WHERE  ts - seconds * interval '1 sec < now();
```

But it's better to transform this into a [*sargable*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable) expression:

```
SELECT *
FROM   tbl
WHERE  ts < now() + seconds * interval '1 sec;
```

[`now()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT) is a Postgres equivalent of the standard form [`CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT) (which you can use as well).

Recent, related answer:
[How do I convert date and seconds fields to a timestamp field in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20505342/how-do-i-convert-date-and-seconds-fields-to-a-timestamp-field-in-postgresql/20506708#20506708)